# How to generate a pdf or text file from windows form application

Tags: database, winforms, pdf, itext, genfromtxt

I am creating a desktop windows form application with database attached.. the first screen consists of a form that user is supposed to fill, if he/she wants to print this form.. is there any solution that a file in pdf form be created dynamically, that user can print?

Besides the record is also saved in database.
I have used iTextSharp it works well for web applications. But i want to generate a file from windows form app. 
Kindly help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any reporting services like sap crystal reports or Birth , then in desktop application populates the data changes through store procedures.
Create report which use this same store procedure.

Once the report is called from desktop app, from the report you have options to export pdf, excel etc.